# Jupyter lab failed push to Github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-lab

I'm getting this error when I tried to push my changes to Github, can anybody help me with this?

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_git\git.py", line 139, in execute code, output, error = await call_subprocess_with_authentication( File "C:\Users\Microsoft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_git\git.py", line 75, in call_subprocess_with_authentication p = pexpect.spawn( AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This looks like a know issue on Windows (see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/492), but I am not sure if an error like that is expected. Did you configure authentication?